# Find all intersectional Periods between a list of dates (for Room reservations)

Tags: python, algorithm, datetime

I need to write a piece of software that organizes room reservations.
In this I need to write a headerbar for a calendar that reconices room confilcts.
Basicly theres rooms and one room can only have one reservation at a time and the header needs to highlight when there is a conflict.
Basicly it needs to look like this:

[image]

For this I would need a list of date ranges in red that show up once more than one reservation use up the same time frame.
Is there some kind of python library I can use for this?
Basicly it needs to take in a List of Tupels of Dates and spit out a list of tupels of non interlapping dates.

Comment: The red and green in the bar does not really match the overlap, does it? (The "red" to the left and right of "Date 3" and the "green" at the end of "Date 5" seems  wrong, but overall, the idea is clear, and those inaccuracies are probably due to doing this by hand)

Comment: Anyway, sorting by start-time and then comparing the current start time to the previous end time should do the trick. For more details, please provide some actual test data and expected results.

Comment: did you see a mistake? it looks okay for me

Comment: thx ill give it a shot

Comment: @tobias_k That doesn't *quite* work. Consider the intervals `(0, 4)`, `(1, 2)`, `(3, 4)`.  Your suggestion will miss that `(3, 4)` is a conflict.

Comment: There is an `interval` package available for general uses.  There are also many solutions for interval-related problems on this site -- you should have been able to mount a coding attack from those resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*... Basicly it needs to take in a List of Tupels of Dates and spit out a list of tupels of non interlapping dates ...*

Sets are perfect for this. The following example code will find all dates not taken, build (ini, end) tuples from that would be stright forward since each tuple would end when you find a non continuos date. Check it out:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime as dt

ranges = [
    ("2018-1-1", "2018-1-31"),   # 1
    ("2018-1-20", "2018-2-10"),  # 2
    ("2018-2-25", "2018-3-15"),  # 3
    ("2018-2-27", "2018-3-20")   # 4
]

# Range 1 and 2 overlaps staring at day (2018-1-20) to day (2018-1-31)
# You have an open window from (2018-2-10) to (2018-2-25)
# And again overlaps in ranges 3 and 4.


# Lets take those ranges specifications in real dates objects.
date_ranges = []
for ini, end in ranges:
    date_ranges.append(
        (
            dt.strptime(ini, "%Y-%m-%d"), 
            dt.strptime(end, "%Y-%m-%d")
        )
    )

# Now in order to be able to use set theory, you need to
# convert those date ranges into sets of data that 
# match your problem.

# I will use set of days, when every element is a different day,
# I,m assuming a day is the unit for meassuring reservation time.

date_sets = []

for ini, end in date_ranges:
    delta = end - ini
    # We don't convert to sets here becouse
    # we want to keep the order til last minunte.
    # Just in case ;)
    dates_ = [ini + timedelta(n) for n in range(delta.days + 1)]
    date_sets.append(dates_)


# Let get also all days invloved in the full date range,
# we need a reference so we can tell what days are free.


all_dates = []
# Assuming date ranges specification are ordered, which is
# the general case.

# Remember that thing about order
# I told earlier?  :)
ini = date_sets[0][0]
end = date_sets[-1][-1]
delta =  end - ini
dates_ = [ini + timedelta(n) for n in range(delta.days + 1)]
all_dates.append(dates_)


# Now we are ready to work with sets.
all_dates = set(*all_dates)
date_sets = map(set, date_sets)

# Having the sets we can operate on them
# see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

# Sice you want the days that are free for rental, 
# we are getting symmetric difference (elements in either s or t but not both)
free_for_rental = all_dates ^ (set.union(*date_sets))


# Printing the result so you can check it.
list_of_free_dates = sorted(list(free_for_rental))

for day in list_of_free_dates:
    print(day)
```

Reponse:

```
2018-02-11 00:00:00
2018-02-12 00:00:00
2018-02-13 00:00:00
2018-02-14 00:00:00
2018-02-15 00:00:00
2018-02-16 00:00:00
2018-02-17 00:00:00
2018-02-18 00:00:00
2018-02-19 00:00:00
2018-02-20 00:00:00
2018-02-21 00:00:00
2018-02-22 00:00:00
2018-02-23 00:00:00
2018-02-24 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort the intervals by start time ascending, then end time descending.

Then run through the list comparing each start time to the maximum previous end time that you've seen.  If the start time is before that end time, you will have found a conflict from `this_start` to `min(max_prev_end, this_end)`.